# How to get deleted exceptions from recurring series from the Rest API

Tags: outlook-restapi

When you create occurring event in Office365 Outlook and delete a single occurrence the change is never reflected in the data consumed from the REST API.

I get the exceptions (modified only) when I populate the occurences of the Series Master:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/XXcalendaridXX/instances?startDateTime=2017-05-20&endDateTime=2099-12-31&$filter=Type%20eq%20'Exception'

This will give me all exceptions that got modified (e.g. time changes). However, it does not return the occurings that got deleted. Is there a way to get modified AND deleted exceptions?

I need this information in order to create a proper "EXDATE" string when I export the Series Master to iCalendar format.

Thank you

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to compare occurrences provided by endpoint (`list 1`) with occurrences calculated based on recurrence rule of a given recurring event (`list 2`).

If there are occurrences from `list 1` that does not present in `list 2`, then that occurrence was deleted.